# Conditional independence for Markov processes

Tags: probability, markov-process

Suppose we have the following, $P_i(Z_t^1=j)=P(X_t^1=j|X_{t-1}^1=i)$ and $P_i(Z_t^2=j)=P(X_t^2=j|X_{t-1}^2=i)$ where $\{X_t^1\}_{t \geq1}$ and $\{X_t^2\}_{t \geq1}$ are 2 discrete-time homogeneous Markov processes and $i,j\in\Omega$ with $\Omega$ countable and finite. We also assume under measure $P_i$ that processes $Z_t^1$ and $Z_t^2$ are conditionally independent given a discrete random variable $Y$, i.e. $P_i(Z_t^1, Z_t^2|Y) = P_i(Z_t^1|Y) P_i(Z_t^2|Y)$, $\forall$ t.

The goal would be to  get an explicit expression of the following joint probability

$P(X_t^1=j_1,X_t^2=j_2) = ?$

Both processes $\{X_t^1\}_{t \geq1}$ and $\{X_t^2\}_{t \geq1}$ are obviously dependent from each other, so how could I compute this probability using the above hypothesis on conditional independence for $Z_t^1$ and $Z_t^2$ ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to realize that (and why) a formula such as $\{A\mid B\}$ makes no sense at all, as $$P(\{A_1\mid B_1\}\cap\{A_2\mid B_2\}\mid Y).$$

Comment: Could you be more explicit on the fact that the above formula does not make any sense please ?

Comment: You first: where did you see/how do you define P({A1∣B1}∩{A2∣B2}∣Y), or even {A1∣B1}∩{A2∣B2}, or even {A∣B}? Please be specific.

Comment: It is the standard notation for conditioning. $\{A|B\}$ simply means "event A conditionally on event B"

Comment: No it is not the standard notation for conditioning. What do you call "event A conditionally on event B"? Please be extra specific. Is this an event? Which one? A number? Which one? Ad lib. The standard notation for conditioning is P(A|B), being a number, for A and B being events.

Comment: Ok let $Z_t^1=X_t^1|X_{t-1}^1$ and $Z_t^2=X_t^2|X_{t-1}^2$ then the first formula can be written as $P(Z_t^1,Z_t^2|Y) = P(Z_t^1|Y)P(Z_t^2|Y) $. That is what I meant with the braces and cap

Comment: This is only shifting the problem: what do you call "Z=X|Y" when X and Y are random variables? Since you use Z in formulas such as P(Z|T) where T is a random variable, it seems that you mean that Z should be a random variable. On which probability space Ω? And how does one define Z(ω) for every ω in Ω? Actually, all these objects (be they A|B with A, B, events, or X|Y with X, Y, random variables) simply do not exist.

Comment: We consider a standard probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Let $X_t^1$ and $X_t^2$ are Markov processes as defined in the first line of the topic and $Z_t$ is obviously a stochastic process. I also mentioned that the 2 Markov processes take value in $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ which are countable and finite state space and $\Omega_1,\Omega_2 \subset \Omega$. Moreover the transitions (as for every Markov process the Markov property applies) are conditionally independent given a random variable, namely $Y$.

Comment: Is this related to my comments? I am afraid not.

Comment: Ok professor, can you explain what a Markov process is to you ?

Comment: Even more unrelated, sorry.

Comment: If you do not know that given that X and Y are random variable, then X|Y is also a random variable, this is not my fault. You do not need to use the probability measure symbol to make it exist

Comment: Kept for posterity: `If you do not know that given that X and Y are random variable(s), then X|Y is also a random variable, this is not my fault.` (Let me repeat one last time: no object such as `X|Y` exists.)

Comment: I really do not understand what bothers you. Why couldn't ${X_t^1=j1|X_{t−1}^1=i1}$ be an event ? The probability measure takes as argument measurable sets. Thus when one writes P(A|B), "A|B" is a measurable set.

Comment: If you are interested to learn why, stop avoiding *every demand* for definition which is pressed upon you. **How do you define the "thing" A|B as an event, for some events A and B?** Unless you address this question, either by writing down a (precise) definition or by providing a (solid) reference, you are just whistling in the wind, not doing mathematics.

Comment: Say I am writing it this way:
$"Z_t^1=z"="X_t^1=z|X_{t-1}^1=x"$. Is it more clear to you ?

Comment: [Suuuure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3eILoQChD_A). OK, I tried, I failed, good luck.

Comment: $P_x(Z_t^1=\cdot) = P(X_t^1=\cdot|X_t^1=x)$

Comment: @chiva: Did is trying to help you, and you're being obnoxious.

Comment: How am I beaing obnoxious ? I just edited the text and moreover I confess that in the first attempt it was unclear.